# Swift (iOS) Plugin - Method not defined in Plugin Error - Cordova

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, plugins

I'm rewriting all plugins from an app from Objective-C to Swift.
These plugins are called by Cordova. All the plugins work fine in Objective-C.

But when I try to run the app with the swift version plugin I got the following Error.

> **ERROR: Method 'getMAC2:' not defined in Plugin 'MACPlugin2'**

I get this error in all method of any plugin that I rewrite to Swift.

Look this plugin code example:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MACPlugin2)
class MACPlugin2 : CDVPlugin {

    func getMAC2(command : CDVInvokedUrlCommand){

        print("########## ENTER MACPLUGIN 2 ###########")

    }


}
```

Someone have an idea of what are happening?

Best,

Flávio

Comment: Try changing it to `getMac2(_ command: ...)`

Comment: Dan, the func name is correct, it is not this the problem

Comment: I meant try adding the `_`, I didn't even notice the different capitalization.

Comment: Dan, worked, this is the problem, i forgot the `_`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan, was right, I just added `_` before the parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Adding the `_` before the parameter was not enough for me. I had to add a `@objc(test:)` before the method as well.

```
@objc(test:)
func test(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I don't know about others. But this works for me with my plugin in `Swift 4.1`.

Comment: The @objc attribute is required on the class declaration and the function declaration.  And for cleaner code, the trailing parenthesis is unnecessary after the @objc attribute, and can be simplified to: `@objc class MACPlugin2 : CDVPlugin` and `@objc func test(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand)`.

Answer (score 5):

My example was as following, without _ it was not working!!
Notice: This solution is a fix for Swift 3

```
@objc(LibCDVP) class LibCDVP : CDVPlugin {
    func echo(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {

        print("method call OK!")

        let msg = command.arguments[0] as? String ?? ""

        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
            messageAs: msg + ",ECHO"
        )

        self.commandDelegate!.send(
            pluginResult,
            callbackId: command.callbackId
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Swift 4.1**, you will have to add the `@objc(action:)` attribute before the function declaration.

You can do it this way:

```
@objc(action:) func action(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    print(command.arguments)
}
```

Or this way, with `_`:

```
@objc(action:) func action(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    print(command.arguments)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated following changes which is working fine: **Cordova**

```
@objc(IovationBlackBox) class IovationBlackBox : CDVPlugin {
    func blackbox(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
```

add extra: **@objc(blackbox:)** in the function

```
@objc(IovationBlackBox) class IovationBlackBox : CDVPlugin {
    @objc(blackbox:) func blackbox(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
```